Power BI dynamic filtering
I have processdata in an SQL table containing values:
datetime, tag_name, tag_value, tag_id etc.
The goal of this visual is to highlight and visualize processdata points in a list:
This list comes from ML algorythm.
Problem is i want to dynamically sort this list from processdata, and i don't know how to.
Say the list x contains tag_names:
wood_price, coal_price, co2_price etc.
So that the power BI raport shows the:
x,y chart with columns in list x from tag_names and their respective tag_values.
Filtered with datetime (i know how to do that)
I am having a problem dynamically filtering the tag_names list.
How can that be done with a list x?
I tried filtering, but i am not sure how to do it.
What i am basically trying to do is, dynamically aka automatically trying to filter a column with a list.
Manual methods that need to be repeated each time dont work for my use case.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
